# PHP Ajax Html on submit issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I have the code following and it all works but the on success / error I can figure it out.

This is settings.php

```
<li><button type="button" onclick="ApimanagementFunctioncall()" id="button1" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><a href="#">Api management</button></a></li>
<script>
    function ApimanagementFunctioncall(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "Apimanagement.php", true);
    xhttp.send();   
    }

    </script>
```

The Apimanagement.php

MySQLI table here.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-left">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddApi"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add Api</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="AddApi" role="dialog">
<?php
include ("ApiAdd.php");
?>
</div>
```

this is the Addapi.php

```
<?php
    $errorMessage = "";
    $UserId = "11";

     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $VarKeyID = $_POST["KeyID"];
       $VarVCode = $_POST["VerificationCode"];
       $errorMessage1 = ""; 
       $errorMessage2 = "";
       $VkeyAdd= ""; $VCodeAdd = "";
        if(empty($VarKeyID) == false){
            if(is_numeric($VarKeyID) == true){
                if(strlen($VarKeyID) !== 8){
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Key Id is not the correct length of 8 numbers!\n");</script>';}
                    else{ $VKeyAdd = "true";}
            }else{$errorMessage1 = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Key Id should only be numbers!");</script>';}
        }else{$errorMessage1 ='<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please Enter a Key ID!");</script>';}

        if(empty($VarVCode) == false){
            if(ctype_alnum($VarVCode) == true){
                if(strlen($VarVCode) !== 64){
                    $errorMessage2 = "Verification Code should be 64 characters!";
                    }else{$VCodeAdd = "true";}              
            }else{$errorMessage2 = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Verification Code should only be letters and numbers!");</script>';}
        }else{$errorMessage2 ='<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please Enter a Verification Code!");</script>';}

        If($VKeyAdd == "true"){
            if($VCodeAdd == "true"){
            echo "Next";}else{echo $errorMessage2;}
        }else{echo $errorMessage1;}
     }
?>

<div  id="AddApi">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <a href="Settings.php" title="Close" class="close"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
            <h2> Add Api Key </h2> 
            <a href="https://community.eveonline.com/support/api-key/CreatePredefined?accessMask=1073741823" target="_blank" class="btn btn-link" role="button">Api create key here</a>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
            Key ID</br> <input type="text" name="KeyID" maxlength="8" value=""></br>
            Verification Code</br> <input type="text" name="VerificationCode" maxlength="64" min="64" value=""></br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" formtarget="_Self">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Now I know some code i have left out but the relevant code is here and works. The issue is when I click the input submit button of the form. It opens up the addApi.php on the server instead I would like it to echo the errors on the input form and if success go to the Settings.php page where the apimanagement.php page is loaded in the div.

Comment: Never call anything in a form `name="submit"` - it is likely not your problem here, but change the name if you ever want to submit using script. Also set the error message in your php and test if it is empty, if not echo. Makes it a LOT easier to see where the error is

Comment: I don't want scripts as well error messages are displayed and none are occurring as the code works. Just not how i would like it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are saying is wrong. What behavior are you expecting? Is it just the fact that it's not going to `Settings.php` when everything is correct? You should be able to do that either with `<script>window.location.href = "Settings.php";</script>` or `header("Location: Settings.php");`.

Comment: Your code is too complicated. Write a diagram of what is calling what. Right now you are mixing normal form posting with plain AJAX when you have jQuery to handle all communication with the server using jQuery $.get and $.post

Comment: http://imgur.com/0sdgxY3  heres a flowchart of what I want to have happen